# Autotask Postman calls

Tags: postman

I am attempting to work with the Autotask Api, would anyone be willing to share some "Postman" Calls to see if i am on the right track?

here is what I have tried.

Post - https://webservices/autotask.net/atservices/1.6/getZoneInfo?

*Key*   --------------  *Value*

UserName ------------ myApiUserName@email.com

Assuming my credentials are correct (im not sharing here) can you help me to understand why this does not work?

Comment: Please provide more detail if you have read their documentation, I couldn't find anything to signup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too am in the early stages of looking into the Autotask API, I can sucessfullly connect to the API from Postman...

- You require an API User Account [not a normal user account]
- The password for the API Account [obviously]
- And a Tracking Indentifier

The API user can be created within Autotask @ Admin> features & settings> Resources/users> new Users. You will need to give the new user account the security level **API User (System)** once you have created the API user account you will need to generate the Tracking Identifier by clicking the Custom [internal intergration] radio button in the bottom right hand corner. Then click the **Generate** button. Once armed with these three bits of information you will need to goto Postman's Authorization tab and enter the API user credentials. Then goto to the Headers tab and Add the

- **Key:** `TrackingIdentifier`
- **Value:** `<Your Tracking Identifier>`

  as this has to be included in the header of all GET, POST, DELETE etc. requests.

Finally you will need to be sure you are using the correct url as depending on where your Autotask tenancy is sitting the url will be different. [take a look at your url whilst logged into Autotask].

Hope this is helpful...